# Why are all the textures in my file pink?

Tags: texturing

I made a character, and its one of my first times texturing, and I saved my character into a new folder, and when I came back to the model ALL the textures were pink, I used to know what to do, but I stopped texturing, how do I bring my textures back?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Pink means that the texture files are missing.

If the texture files are still on your system, then it sounds like the textures are referenced relative to the blend file (the default behavior). This means that if you move the blend file and you don't move the textures, blender won't be able to find them.

There are several things you can do:

- Use the *Find Missing Files* operator in *Info > File > External Data* to let blender try to find the files for you:

  [image]

  This will give you a file browser with which you can select a directory which you think contains some (or all) missing files. Blender will then recursively search through all files and subdirectories of the selected directory for files with the same names as the missing files.

  Note that if the directory is big (contains lots of files and subdirectories), this might take a while. Blender will appear frozen while the operator runs, but don't panic.
- With the blend file in the original location (so the textures are loaded correctly), press *Make All Paths Absolute* in *Info > File > External Data*, 
  then save the blendfile. Now blender can find the textures (provided they don't move) no matter where the file is on the system.
- Pack the textures into the blendfile. Press *Info > File > External Data > Pack into blendfile*. This will embed the image data into the blendfile itself, so your file may become rather large. However, this means that blender will always be able to find the textures no matter what (even if the file is put on another computer).
- Move the textures to be in the same position relative to the new blend as they were to the old blend. E.g., if the textures are in a directory that is in the same directory as the old .blend, move that directory into the directory containing the new .blend.

Comment: Note, in my case, "missing" simply meant that Blender didn't like the file name. `MyTexture_1024.jpg` did not work, but renaming it to `MyTexture.jpg` did work.

Answer (score 10):

Pink display means missing texture image. Maybe you forgot to *pack* the image files or *save* them to external files, before saving the .blend file and closing Blender.

If that's the case, unfortunately you'll have to re-make the texture images..

Answer (score 5):

Altought this is resolved already, here is a help:
When you open texture tab, find this:
[image: Change pink color to black]

Make sure to change pink color to black. Than it should be fixed, I think...

Comment: Welcome to the site :) This is useful information to have here, thanks for adding it. But note that this won't bring the textures back, it will just change the pinkness to blackness instead.

Comment: Ohhh that's where the Pink of Doom™ comes from!

Comment: @gandalf3 By the way, there is no need to Pack into .blend file always you save game- it is annoying and hard to remember. You can check the box in _File->External Data_ so it does it automaticly;)

Comment: @AdriansNetlis. Hi. Please can you tell me where I can find the texture tab? Because in Textures I have brush-texture and brush mask. I can't find the screen what you are talking about.

Comment: @Meri On the top you could look for 3 icons - Earth, cube and checkers. Click on cube.
P.S. This is old post, those days I had so low knowledge of Blender. It has grown a lot so this answer made by me seams to be foolish:D

Comment: @AdriansNetlis Thank you but I can' find those options. I am in the cube and I have opened every ticker. I'll do the model again. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the textures disappeared. You should make sure the textures are downloaded. If you save your files in iCloud I suggest you double check the folder with the model and texture.