# Leaf texture is not mapping correctly onto leaves?

Tags: texturing, add-on

I am using sapling addon to create a tree. A tutorial says that the sapling addon is meant to map the leaves perfectly, once you add a texture. However, it isn't doing this when I try.

Instead, the leaves just come up colourful.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32879

Comment: You need to pack the textures into the blend file

Comment: to pack your textures see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/1853

Comment: it seemed that you press unwrap for all the leafs try to make it one more time without pressing anything

Comment: and by the way you shouldn't put the image as a color for the transparent node,you should make the color 100% white