# Missing texture paint option in blender

Tags: texturing, uv

My cube object is appearing pink. I want to paint on it but blender is saying that texture files are missing.

How do I correct it?

Is there anything I need to import?

Comment: You should add a screenshot to help describe the actual problem you're facing

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Comment: Are your textures missing? Make sure the paths are pointing to the files correctly.