# Texture Painting mode: Missing data warning

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I try to do a projection painting and I followed a tutorial, but I get a **'Missing Data' warning** in the tool shelf:

[image]

**How do I solve this?** This is what I want to achieve (picture of the tutorial):

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I think you haven't applied / saved  (if .blend was reopened) material with texture for that mesh. You should create material, texture for that material, and open / create image in the `Image Editor` which then apply for that texture. Also it might be a good idea to include link to the lesson you use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Comment: Welcome :) Leave a comment or edit your question, if the link above does not solves your issue. Please start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour to get your first badge. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!

Comment: when I do that "add a diffuse color" thing it applies it to one part of my mesh.

Answer (score 6):

To paint on the model you need to create a texture in the material.

Click on **Add Paint Slot** and select **Diffuse Color**.
This will create a texture that will have Color influence on the material in Blender Internal, and if you are in Cycles Render it will add a texture node on the material.

[image]

Comment: After this, I cannot see the `Tool` option. How find it out?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you don't have *Use Nodes* checked in your *Node Editor* window. This should let you paint in the *3D Viewport*. I had the same problem and this worked for me.