# Texture painting turns pink

Tags: texturing

When I try to go and texture paint, my object turns pink and I do not have access to paint brushes. I smart unwrapped the object already. This is in blender render. I also get the message Missing data.

[image: pink texture]

Comment: The question isn't the same as the suggested duplicate.

Comment: The question indeed isn't a duplicate of linked one and can be reopened (and to be closed as a duplicate of another one). Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/texture-painting-mode-missing-data-warning

Answer (score 3):

You missed this little step here ...

1. For the type, add image texture.
2. Point the target to the texture named "untitled" you have created in your image editor.
3. Change the Mapping Coord from "Generated" to "UV" - [Paul Gonet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/7797/paul-gonet)

[image]

**Additional Notes**
 When you are done painting your texture go to the UV/Image editor and press F3 to save the image. Otherwise all of your work will be lost. Saving the blend file will not save the image with it. Please read this link: [Why did the texture I painted in texture paint mode disappear?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear)

> Image painting will display in render view mode in Cycles setup, but
>   to make  sure the image renders, you need to save the image to
>   directory and save the changes you make. Many users forget to do this,
>   and assume that saving the file will save the state of the image
>   painting, and this is false. In the Image Editor, you can choose 'save
>   image' or 'save image as' and iterate changes to new images if you
>   want. You can also indicate 'pack into file' from there, as well as
>   'pack external data' from the File header. - [Craig D Jones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/12662/craig-d-jones)

Comment: Also remember to change the coordinates from 'Generated' to 'UV'.

Comment: @hawkenfox can you please put the text not only on the image, but as part of the answer. The text on the image is not searchable, so others might not be able to reach this answer via web search engines...

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. When I have drawn on the cube, will it appear during render?

Comment: Image painting will display in render view mode in Cycles setup, but to make sure the image renders, you need to save the image to directory and save the changes you make. Many users forget to do this, and assume that saving the file will save the state of the image painting, and this is false. In the Image Editor, you can choose 'save image' or 'save image as' and iterate changes to new images if you want. You can also indicate 'pack into file' from there, as well as 'pack external data' from the File header.