# How to use texture paint in Blender Render

Tags: rendering

I had to use the edge split modifier and it makes my model IMPOSSIBLE to unwrap, so I just had to project from view, now its basically necessary for me to finish with texture paint but I have to keep it in blender render because the model will be going in a game.  When I select texture paint in blender render the model is just purple.

Comment: If you mean you applied Edge Split modifier then it's obvious that unwrapping will be more complex. Unwrap before applying that modifier (or remove doubles, unwrap and re-add modifier). As for pink texture painting - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/texture-painting-mode-missing-data-warning

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I got it, I had to add a texture image then select the texture that I had on the UV map.