# UV textures appear scrambled or missing

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

UV textures appear scrambled or missing when rendered, but are fine in the 3D view. I've spent the entire day googling and looking at other people's problems and I am still at a loss. I want to render now but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

[Blendfile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/126066185/helpme.blend)

Am I missing something obvious? I have more than one UV on a character and want to know if it's possible to assign different materials to different parts.

Sorry if I'm not providing enough details. If you have questions, I'll try to answer right away.

Comment: Would you mind [uploading a .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) of your project file (be sure to pack textures, *Flie* > *External Data* > *Pack all into .blend* before you save the file for upload), and [add it to your post, as an edit](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/AdvancedHelp.gif).

Comment: I added the file!

Comment: The textures appear to be missing in your uploaded file. Did you [pack](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5368/599) the textures before uploading?

Answer (score 1):

You have only 1 UV on each character and your UVs intersect.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add more to this answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how to fix these issues?

Comment: Is there a way I can amend this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at these two tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqmXqgbzIxg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNtIX5BZmzc

Which allowed the characters to have their full skin map and t-shirt design map to be separate - and no overlap. (Creating UV Maps under *Data* with the appropriate mesh selected. Then creating a material and texture - making sure the correct UV map was selected under Mapping. And lastly, "assigning" the material to the piece.)

And then this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GYvjqjYr90) allowed me separate UV's that had transparency to render! (Selecting Face Textures and Face Textures Alpha under Materials > Options).

https://sketchfab.com/models/cf6bf7d8729f479ab0522e73317b29fe

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Please add more, or include important steps from the tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that each single UV map has been assigned to its object.
If you can't select each part:

1. Switch to Edit mode
2. Hover your mouse over the part you want to select and press L. The part will be highlighted.
3. Now assign your UV map.
4. Switch back to object mode, click on the general object and repeat these steps with each single part from step 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it all you normals are inverted for one.

A black mesh can mean your materials aren't connected or you're using adaptive subsurf with a normal map set to tangent space.