# How would I apply a gloss or anisotropic shader to my model?

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image: Model in Perspective]

I'm using an older version of blender and i'm having trouble finding how to apply a gloss or anisotropic shader to the model in blender engine. I'm attempting to apply the shader to the grip and the slide (The gold and dark gray segments) any help would be appreciated.

[image]

enter image description here

Comment: The .blend you uploaded is missing its textures, so please [pack](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/1253) them and re-upload the file.

Comment: sorry forgot that, should be good now

Comment: Were you able to get your materials working?

Answer (score 2):

Your mesh objects are not rendering because many of them have Material issues. Either they do not have a material set up, OR they have the wrong material type for the render engine chosen. You have the Blender Internal engine selected, but your materials nodes seem to have been set up in Cycles originally.

Changing the engine to Cycles allows all the objects to render, so the solution depends on which engine you are intending to use.

If you do actually want to use the BI engine, then you need to replace your the nodes in your Materials to use BI type nodes with a proper BI output node.