# Shading issue with textured solid model

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

Seems like something went wrong here.
Already tried to re-unwrap the wrong displayed parts of the mesh, also changing shading mode from smooth to flat and back to smooth. It still looks like this:

[image: Model Issue Example]

However, it seems like it actually doesn't have to do with the material shading. What else can I do to let it being displayed correctly?

Recalculating the normals did NOT work. It still only appears in "textured solid", pure solid mode shows the model like it should. Else no errors in the texture itself.

[image: Mesh settings screenshot]

.blend-file:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to recalculate normals

Comment: Tried, but with no changes to the displayed mesh.

Comment: Can you add a snapshot with mode details like UVs, modifiers etc...

Comment: It seems most likely to be an issue with the UV map. Those overlapping UVs near the bottom look suspicious, but it's hard to tell what might be going on without a closer look. Is it possible you could upload the .blend (with packed textures)?

Comment: If you could explain me what you mean with packed textures and how I can do that, sure.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/599. Packing the textures will embed them into the .blend so that they go wherever the .blend goes.

Comment: Okay, done that. How can I 'upload' the .blend file now?

Comment: @xDonnervogelx Upload it to some hosting service (e.g. [pasteall](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/system_keyboard_svg.py) or [blendexchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)) and put the link here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, managed to upload it (well yesterday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *vertex color* layer on the object which is causing this.
Remove it in *Properties > Object Data > Vertex Colors:*

[image]