# UV texturing mesh object won't turn black in texture painting mode

Tags: texturing, materials

Im following a video series by Darrin Lile (Texture painting part 1) my mesh doesnt turn black when I change to blender render, change from data to object, assign a new material, and switch the texture painting. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: are you sure this object is selected ?

Comment: Yes I am sure :)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you don't have texture slot to paint on (warning about that and ways to correct are in the top of the <kbd>T</kbd> panel):

[image]

You have assigned material, set shading to *GLSL*, set Viewporrt shading to *Texture* and turned on *Texture Paint*. Thus the pink color - Blender's warning regarding to leak of texture, wasn't shown. If you switch back to *Solid* shading, you can see that the mesh is pink (tbh, this was the only way I could avoid of getting pink color in the beginning of the Texture painting). See [why the textures are pink](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink), or [why the mesh is pink in Texture Paint](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?226606-mesh-is-pink-when-viewport-shading-is-set-to-quot-textured-quot).

I think it's quite handy to start this work being in the Solid Viewport shading. Then if image is missing you can notice that, while you'll see the texture in all details once it's added:

[image]