# Render layer causing image "shearing" in video sequence editor

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, render-layers

I'm having an issue where black "v" shapes or jagged lines show up in my render.  They almost look as though the image is being ripped apart and the black background underneath is showing through.

[image: parallax video black anomaly]

Through process of elimination I've narrowed down the source of the problem to be the Render Layer titled "text shadows".  This layer consists of duplicate text objects that I've added a blur node to in the compositor to create a shadow effect.  I've tried to troubleshoot the problem by removing nodes in the compositor, hiding or deleting my mask object in each scene, and adjusting the position of the text shadow objects in y space.  The only way I've found to remove the black shapes is to turn the "text shadows" render layer off altogether in the Render Layer panel.  After doing so the render turns out fine, but I can't achieve the look I'm going for without the shadows behind the text.  Any insight into what is causing this issue and how to prevent it would be extremely helpful.  Also, I'll include the .blend.  I'm using Blender Internal.

[image]

Comment: Please reupload the file with the images included. See [this thread](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink) for more info on including textures used in your file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Is there a way I can reduce the size of the .blend after "packing" the file?  The file size is too large to upload via Blend-Exchange (my file is now 34 MB and Blend-Exchange only allows up to 30 MB).

Comment: If the only heavy thing that you used in the file are images then you can only: 1) make a stripdown version, so cutting some effects in order to delete image from file completely and not use it anymore 2) use images of lower resolution and / or another formats. The most simple one is .jpeg. Note that all this is applicable only to simple version of file for uploading.

Comment: Makes sense.  I went ahead and swapped the PNG textures out with JPEG versions.  The updated .blend is now in the description :)

Comment: Could you upload the render image where you turned "Text Shadows" off?

Comment: I can't find what you describe in the file you uploaded...

Answer (score 0):

As cegaton mentionend, the file you uploaded won't produce such problems on my side neither:

http://sendvid.com/tbu3umgk
[image: VLC example screenshot]

Though I had to disable your dust layers to get another result than lots of white:

[image: Dust-Layer problem]

However, I suppose, it's a driver problem on your side. I already had a graphics cards driver problem with Blender. The developers helped me [out](https://developer.blender.org/T45270#319163) to find out whether the problem is one with the driver.

You should use the *opengl32.dll* from http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/ and place it next to *blender.exe* as described by sergey to find out if the problem is your driver. Beware, that Blender might be very slow while using this wrapper dll as everything is done on CPU only without using your graphics card.