# How do I import textures with a 3d model?

Tags: texturing, materials, import

So I've downloaded this 3d model of a car

http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/audi-r8-14024.html

However it doesn't load the textures.

Trying to render from the Audi R8- Studio Render Scene.blend shows this.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVSXg.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using cycles or internal?

Comment: @Tim, the first image above is Cycles, the next two showing are Blender Internal.

Comment: I'm clicking the Render button with the little camera icon. I guess whatever is the deafult one.

Comment: Select Blender render or Cycles render from the dropdown menu at the top under the file title.

Comment: Switching between them doen't solves anything. Only makes the car look granulated but still grey.

Comment: I think the problem isn't a render problem but more of a texture problem.

Comment: When you see pink on the render it means that the texture is missing or is mapped incorreclty. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you downloaded is poorly setup. The image textures on the blend file are not packed, are missing or have a different name that that on the file (hence the pink). You could re-link them manually to the provided images on the textures folder and maybe that will work. The rest of the materials are really for you to experiment and make whatever you want out of them. 
[image: 1]