# Model still appearing pink after applying image.

Tags: texturing

So I just started learning how to texture paint and am following this tutorial (https://youtu.be/LcCQKuWPhXk)

I followed everything up to the point where you add the image texture node.
When I add it, the image remains pink instead of turning black. Is there anything that's normally expected when texture painting that I missed?

[image]

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/19287

Comment: The Image Texture node's color output needs to be connected to the Diffuse node's color input.

Comment: Did that solve it?

Comment: Image Texture's node color output does not need to be connected to the Diffuse's node for texture painting, it's enough placing node in the node tree. It would be required if you try render that. It's quite strange that Blender didn't show that image, probably it would help reloading it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can unwrap the object in glsl texture mode then import the texture and attach it to a material by adding a material, applying it to the faces you want textured, selecting the material, going to the textures tab, new, material. you can then edit the uv map of the object how you like
[image]

Comment: There's just one issue with this, but a pretty major one. The OP is using Cycles, which is quite different from Blender Internal.