# Brush library in Blender

Tags: texture-painting

I need to paint textures by hand in Blender (I currently use the 2.8 Alpha version).
I created several brushes from image texture, with different settings and now I would like to save them for later use in other scenes.

What's the process for exporting the created brushes (if possible)? Is there any way to create a brush library in texture paint/sculpt mode to view and select them easily? Kind of like in Gimp or Photoshop.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52483/how-to-import-brush-sets/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't export anything from Blender to Blender. You simply keep them in a .blend file and append them when you need (File → Append).

However, unused textures are considered as orphan data. In Blender, orphan data are not kept in the .blend file, so they disappear as soon as you close it.

So, in order to force them to stay in your library .blend file, you will have to open the outliner, switch to the orphan data view, and check every data you want to keep. (Those kept have a checkmark, those unkept have an X instead, click the mark to switch between.)

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you! Is there a way to associate an image to each brush, instead of the draw icon for example? I won't be the only one using them and it would be great if we could see them in the display before selecting them

Comment: Under 'Overlay' in the tool properties, there is 'Custom Icon' and there you can assign a custom image for the brush.

Answer (score 1):

One way to categorize your brushes, and store them with previews is the BlenderKit library. It only works online. You can upload and share your brushes, and there are already about 100 sculpting brushes by now, but almost no texture brushes. In Blender 2.8 it's inside blender already, for 2.79 you can download it from the site:https://www.blenderkit.com/get-blenderkit/

[image]