# Saving brushes into the pallete in 2.8

Tags: sculpting

just wondering how to import brushes into 2.8 and have them be there when I open a new file.

I downloaded a .blend file with some cool brushes that are in the file and are categorized with the existing brushes, but then they disappear when I go to open one of my designs.

Let me know if you have the solution!

-MC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import brush sets?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52483/how-to-import-brush-sets)

Answer (score 2):

You have to append the files of the brushes that are in brush folder of that blend file that contains it. And if you want to use them every time, open a new blender file and do what I told above and then go to file, save startup file and you are done. Happy sculpting!

Comment: This is supposed to work, but when I start a new file, I only have the last custom selected brush available. I have to append everything again if I want to work with these new brushes.

Comment: @Azuk hello this days brush settings and the reset brushes and all that stuff related its kinda still broken in the latest blender builds...you will have to wait until devs fix that...so you will have to append your brushes and edit your brush settings everytime you open your file i guess...

Comment: I found this post when researching the same problem and I think I found a solution: when appending the brushes from the .blend file, you need to check the option "Fake User", otherwise since the brushes are not in use, they're discarded. Pretty much the same thing that happens with unused textures and other data types.
I did that and I was able to have all the brushes available the next time.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Blender 2.91:

I had the problem of missing preview images. To describe the package, the images were seperately stored in a folder with png files so I had to relink them to the .blend. Following helped:

- Save brush file  und brush image folder to AppData > Roaming > Blender Foundation > Blender > *Version* > config
- Open up brush file, relocate preview images, make pathes absolute, save
- Open up new file > append brushes (from the AppData Version .blend), save to startup file (make shure to click Fake User)
- Open up startup file (in AppData > ...), make pathes absolute, save
- Done

This is definetly not practical, as your pathes probably will have to stay absolute on every new file. But not making the startup file relative messes with the image folder filepath. Perhaps you can 'bake' the images.