# Importing new brushes into existing .blend file

Tags: sculpting

Can I import new brushes into an existing blender 2.8 file? I'm able to open a new file and have the brushes show up, but not in an older model.

Thanks,
MC

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129875/saving-brushes-into-the-pallete-in-2-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import brush sets?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52483/how-to-import-brush-sets)

Answer (score 1):

File -> Append. Then click on the file with brushes you need and on the folder Brushes

[image]