# Why are there dfferences between Textured and Rendered modes?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have assigned a material with an image texture to this cube (I think) and when viewed in Texture mode I see this

[image]

When viewed in Rendered Mode I see this

[image]

This suggests I did not properly assign the material but why is it visible in Texture mode ? I know why I get this purple color but the question is why I see this purple color in Rendered Mode and not in Texture mode (this is why this question is not a duplicate imo)

Comment: How did you apply the texture? How is the material applied? Cycles or Blender Internal? Could you edit you question and provide more info, like a material setup screenshot? It may happen that you are just seeing your UV unwrap in the viewport, and didn't properly create a material with a texture.

Comment: this could be the case  .... but how is it possible that I see the image texture in Texture mode and not in Rendered mode ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Comment: Texture mode shows unwrapped textures even if they aren't applied to a material yet for preview purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like you have moved the texture after you brought it into blender. You need to relocate the texture. When blender renders it loads the texture from disk (and is unable to find it causing the purple). The material view is using the copy in memory. When the file is saved and reloaded the material view will purple as well.

Comment: yes but can you explain why the image texture is visible in Texture mode and not in Rendered mode ?

Comment: It is visible in textured view because the texture is still in memory. Texture are stored in memory on image load to improve performance. This means that if the file is moved or adjusted blender doesn't update. You still see the texture. This memory *only* gets emptied when blender is quit. Rendered mode does not use memory and instead attempts to read from disk, is unable to find the file, and shows as purple.