# Image texture is visible in Texture mode but not in Render mode?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, image, uv-image-editor

Here, it is visible

[image]

But,
in Render mode,

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58265/why-are-there-dfferences-between-textured-and-rendered-modes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons why blender can't find it, here are a couple things you could try:

- **Try re-opening the image**. As seen in @CyberBurst's answer, make sure the file is in the correct location. If the image is not in the same location that blender is looking for it in, Blender will not find it. Also if the spelling is off that would prevent blender from finding it too...
- If you are sure the image is in the right location, and that the spelling is correct, **try packing textures into the blend file** To pack do: *Blender-> File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend*

If it is still not working, try to restart blender and repeat the steps again. If it is STILL not working then either something is wrong with blender, or the image. Try opening a different image instead of that one in blender. If the new image appears correctly then something is wrong with your image, otherwise something is wrong with blender, and in this case I would recommend starting from the beginning with a blender session.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure the image is still in the location you pointed Blender to.  Sometimes, if the file has been moved, Blender will still have it in memory, so it still displays it in textured mode.  But when you click the render button, Blender will search for the image in the original file, and in your case, it apparently can't find it.  Double check your image texture node to make sure it is pointing to the right file.  Then, go to the file and make sure the image is still there.