# How do I mirgrate all image textures to a different folder?

Tags: texturing

I imported an .OBJ that has large amount of image textures onto my desktop but I don't want to keep them there as I want to place the textures into the another folder.

Do I have to manually reassign every texture or is there a better way to change the location of a large amount of texture images?

Comment: Normally, in Wavefront, the texture paths are relative to the main obj file. If you move the obj file along all used files, there should be no problem. Is this your case?

Comment: Thing is I want to keep textures in their own folder and the prop in another instead of all in one.

Comment: Use *Find Missing Files* after moving folder somewhere and point Blender to that somewhere, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/1245

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have many Wavefront materials and you are copying all images from the same location to another location (also same for all pictures), open the .mtl file and replace all texture paths manually. You can try to speed this process up by using well-placed replace commands.

Otherwise, you'll need to write a script that reads all the path and edits them manually.

- Read the file line-wise
- Split each line by space. The first sub string will be the command
- on "map_kd" and other map commands, read the rest of the string a path.
- Edit the path. In Java you move a path `path` from path `from` to path `to` with the following code: `to.resolve(from.toAbsolutePath().relativize(path));`
- Overwrite the line

You can also import the file as is if the program you used for importing supports moving source files.

And don't forget:

### Always back up your files!