# Killing Multiple Data Blocks

Tags: uv

I have some large models with lots of texture data blocks.

In an effort to structure my models I have moved my images that are UV textures to a library folder and this has resulted in a .blend file with hundreds of data blocks I need to unlink.

Now I do know how to use shift with the deselect button in the UV Image Editor but the only way to get to this data us the tiny drop down menu that shows 10 at a time.

Is there any way to make this a screenful every time you open this drop down it also starts at the top with a list of over 290 data blocks scrolling down is becoming a pain and I have two more modes one of these has even more blocks.

Comment: If you mean that you moved some files to a folder and they are missing in the blend now use File > Find Missing Files and navigate to that folder, see [related answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/1245). Your second part of question like "Is there any way to make this a screenful every time" is not clear, you could [edit] it to clarify

Comment: Perhaps try the *Outliner* in *Data Blocks* mode. You can browse down the file tree structure and micromanage many aspects of it.

Comment: Thanks it looks like Outliner in Data Blocks mode could be what I am after. I just did not know it was there later today I will try this with one of my files

Comment: I have looked at this Yes I can see all of the Textures data blocks but how do I remove all of the links for any particular block?