# Strange indication to a missing UV-Map?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv

Good day.

For some reason I see a strange purple reflection in my scene. I know that this is usually an indication to a missing UV-Map. But I unwrapped every object in my scene. The background is transparent with an image added in the compositor.

Do you guys have some ideas where this might come from?

[image]

Comment: Purple (magenta or more known as pink) is the indication of missing *texture*, i.e. image file accessible to Blender for opening. As those bolts seem to be glossy they could reflect it from environment hdr setup as pink can be also seen in the bottom right. Check if hdr image's loading correctly. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The image is visible in the background as it is supposed to be, BUT: I indeed forgot that I tried to use a world-background when I started the scene. And that was - as you mentioned - the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comments - I'm just getting old.

Gone is the purple reflection:

[image]

[edit]
Sorry for the missing details. I forgot that I wanted to use a world background image at the beginning. Therefore I changed the surface type to "image" without actually asigning one. That caused the reflections.

Comment: It's advised here to include some details into your answer without relying to comments; as of now the answer itself doesn't tell anything why is it answer. Add screenshots of setup and several statements elaborating on the topic.