# how do I fix this weird thing where my objects turn purple

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

so I did some stuff, and made a character. And then I had to go so I saved it and turned off my computer. The next day I woke up and then I opened the file and saw it looks like this

[image: screenshot-1]
https://gyazo.com/19a4ad6cc6eea2a4e33aee761c5cf977

[image: screenshot-2]
https://gyazo.com/852697c86ae713e8cab26d5fc404defd

I did not do anything to make it purple when I was saving it. I am using blender 2.77

Comment: HI. Please use the built-in image uploading feature here on StackExchange. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Pink means missing data (i.e. textures). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Answer (score 2):

Pink mesh mean that you're trying to load a texture that's missing. Check that textures have been loaded correctly and/or haven't been moved.