# How can I move an object with a UV map to a DIFFERENT project?

Tags: uv, normal-map

I've got an object that I developed in one project that has been decimated and makes use of a UV map. When I copy the object into a new project, the object comes over and the UV map comes over, but the texture that is overlaid on the UV map seems to get lost in the shuffle. The object is just a splattering of purples and blues (the UV map).

Comment: Pack the texture. File>External Data.

Comment: See Link and Append on the file menus.

Comment: Exporting geometry in most exchange formats preserves UV maps for it. How do you "move" objects - do you export e.g. into .FBX format and import into another scene or do you append saved mesh from one .blend to another? What does it mean "splattering of purple and blue"? If you mean you opened new .blend, appended the object from another .blend file and it's pink when rendered then see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Comment: @MrZak I followed other people's suggestions for moving an object from one blender file to another- simply have both open and copy and paste. Your question obviously points to another path and that is to export as an object and open it up in a new project. Let me give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you want to move the image texture connected to the object's material to your new project file. There's two ways i know how to do that.

You can go to your old project, open the UV/Image editor tab, select your image and click Image > Save As Image. You can then bring this image into your new project from the location where you saved it at.

[image]

Another option is to append the files from your old project into your new one. You can do this by pressing Shift+F1 or by going to File > Append. From there you must locate your old .blend and find the required files in the corresponding folders.

[image]

I hope this was useful to you. I'm sorry if i misread your question, feel free to correct me.