# I am making a minecraft animation, and all my textures are missing

Tags: animation, texturing

I am making an animation, and all of the textures went away. I had mcprep downloaded, and when I clicked prep materials, none of them came! Please help!

Comment: Please elaborate a bit

Comment: i think u delete the image where the image where or shifted that image to some other location. Have u pack the image

Comment: Does this help? [Find missing files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)  A screenshot or two often sheds light.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used mcprep before, but this sounds like what has happened to me before with other projects, and it is usually due to the location of your textures changing, meaning blender is searching for the image in the wrong file location. Try searching for the file locations and then reassigning the location of the texture in the texture tab.