# Blender Cycle bug imported png is pink while Jpg is not

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image]

Guys help!. the blender cycle cant read png I even unwrap it.

Comment: Can assure you png's work. Post a screenshot with image open in the image editor. [Pink on image textures indicates the file is missing.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink/5372?s=1|0.0000#5372)

Comment: I already done that Find missing file

Comment: I even tried to create another blender app then put PNG image but this is the same result

Comment: If your png uses transparency you should plug the alpha factor into a mix shader (the one for mixing shader, not colours.) Alpha->fac, Transparent shader in the upper input, textured surface shader in the bottom.

Comment: What happens if you use the add image as planes addon and import your png that way? Does it render correctly now?

Comment: actually thats what i used