# How do I change the file path for all the textures used?

Tags: texturing

I have made a scene in blender following some tutorials, however, since my C drive was getting too loaded, I shifted all my Blender stuff to the D drive. Now when I make a render in blender, all objects have a Purple colour to them. Reading other questions, I figured that it might be because the source of all the image textures have been shifted from C to D drive.

I changed the source of my textures on the current model I am working on through the node editor, however, for all my other .blend files, do I have to correct each textures location file one by one or is there an easier way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Comment: Side note: Always use relative paths for external data .Always put all project assets inside the same parent folder.

Comment: did you try file -> external data -> find missing files?

Comment: I have a problem that I believe is related to the conversation below. We have a scene set up and working properly, but the texture sizes are too large for our needs. We want to use lower-resolution textures instead, but we're unsure how to make Blender read the new textures from a different location. Can you help us with this issue?

Answer (score 30):

*File -> External Data -> Find missing files* -> Choose your texture folder -> *Find missing files*.

Blender will then replace all missing textures with the fitting ones from the new selected folder.

Comment: From five years in the future, thank you. Life saver.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and wrote an add-on to help, it's here:

https://github.com/cskilbeck/bl_TextureLocator

It's still in Testing but if it's useful we can see about getting it migrated into the repo.

Comment: Wouldn't this addon still require manually switching for each material? Is it possible to switch folders for all the materials?

Comment: I'll look into it, I'll update the GitHub issue if/when I get it done