# Why does part of my model's texture appear purple?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

In the rendered viewport the model appears as it should, however, when I actually render it, part of the texture appears purple, which normally means I'm missing a texture but only part of the texture is purple, which doesn't make any sense. Also, all the textures are in the directories that they should be, I don't see what the issue is.
Ive attached the .blend file here:[image]

And the textures here:[image]

[image]

Comment: Can´t see anything abnormal with your file, could you clarify what the issue is? Specifically what part is not as expected?

Comment: Basically when I render the image, part of the texture on the character’s head become purple and I don’t k ow why.

Comment: Bad UV map I'd assume, there is purple on what I presume is the nose. The UVs look very messy, which means it is probably bleeding onto some part that it shouldn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Answer (score 1):

I find the issue to my problem, I had a second object that I had hidden in the 3d view, and then forgot about. This caused it to appear in the render image, and the hidden object was using a texture that I had deleted causing it to be purple. It was also in the same place as the object that was normal, causing the overlapped portion to appear purple.