# Not only did my textures go pink. Now the background is pink as well.

Tags: texturing

I have deleted all of the textures but everything, including the background, is now pink and there's nothing I seem to be able to do.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink/5372#5372 (Possible Duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

The pink color you see is correct, because so Blender informs you that an image is missing, this is an added utility to quickly check the missing images in large projects. To resolve this you need to detach or remove the link to the image.

[image]