# Textures are missing somehow

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor

Still need help. The textures are missing, I already tried to report and find missing files, but it's not working for me. I put in nodes to try to help it, but it didn't help any further. The final renderings are still missing textures for some reason...

[image]

[image]

Here's a link to this file if you have any solutions: [image]

Comment: Please do not ask the same question many times. Edit your original post instead. If you are sharing a file sharing your .blend file  [**Pack the images used as textures**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)

Answer (score 1):

[**Pink means missing textures**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

You are using image textures that are not assigned to use any image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a lighting issue overpowering the model even in user perspective window. Try messing with the light sources and re-rendering to see if there is a difference anywhere.