# Textures on models randomly disappeared in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I need help. I was working on my first real animation which involved lightsabers. I wasn’t sure if the character models I was using would work in cycles render, so I tested it out and they worked fine while also a great lightsaber effect. I worked on it and am almost done. But when I start blender to continue all of a sudden the textures don’t appear. When I click textured they still look solid. When I go rendered they are pink. I tried to see what they looked like in blender render and they have no textures at all there! The textures straight disappeared. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Comment: *"when I start blender to continue "* do you mean you restarted Blender? If yes did you save the image before closing it? *" I tried to see what they looked like in blender render"* Blender render and Cycles are different render engines with too different material settings so this is completely normal

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I figured out what was wrong. Apparently my textures were still downloading on my computer. They didn’t finish downloading. Now it’s working. Sorry.