# Background colour in cycles render turning pink

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to set the background to blue yet whatever I do it still comes out as pink. Any ideas how to fix this?
[image: picture]

Comment: Pink is usually the color for a missing texture, here maybe the environment texture. Could you upload your .blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add it to your question by editing it? That would help figuring it out efficiently rather that having to guess

Comment: Alright, I thought maybe it might be a simple common issue

Comment: Well, it is, but it is kind of weird why your background is set to a color and it basically shows a missing environment texture.. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink. When uploading the .blend please make sure to include all data: File->External Data->Pack all into .blend

Comment: Why did you ask for  file if you just linked to another question saying its the solution?

Comment: It might well be the solution, im just offering you additional help because I'm in the mood for it

Comment: Not really sorry, its talking about texture and not about the world surface

Comment: You can set a 360° texture as your 'world (environment)'-background. If that texture is missing, the world goes pink

Comment: Pink means that whatever is supposed to be there is missing, either the link is broken, the texture file is in a different place in the drive or has been deleted, etc. It is also possible that there is something going on in the compositor, but it is hard to guess without more information.

Answer (score 2):

You might have changed the directory of the background image or the image file. While rendering do not move files around.

Comment: I'm not using a backgound image, its a background colour

Comment: Also I changed the colours image and its still pink and I switched it to sky texture and its still pink.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a new .blend file and copy/paste everything into it.

To select everything simply press <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, open a new window of Blender and paste everything there.