# Cycles render stopped rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm trying to render out my file but it stopped at frame 178 and now I can't get it to continue rendering, it just doesn't seem to do anything and then the software says its not responding. I've tried rendering it on my MacBook and now on my boyfriend's PC to no avail.[image]

Link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nwHD-AH2b-O3NW2531x5XOnbD8xxiBJY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the file. What happens at that particular frame of the animation? Are you rendering using GPU?

Comment: Yes I was rendering using GPU and also tried with CPU. I would attach the file but tried to and it said it was too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame renders just fine, it just takes a very, very, very long time to synchronize the objects... You are using a highly subdivided model. In my opinion you don't need that many vertices.

Try simplifying the topology and reduce the number of vertices as much as you can.

[image]

Additionally, instead of animating the visibility of the objects, play with shapekeys, so that you are dealing with a constant number of vertices for the start and end of the morph transformation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m new to 3D animation so not really got my head round all of it yet. Not sure how to use shapekeys but I will look into it. Thank you. Not sure why it’s rendering purple but I’ll look at my material nodes and check them.

Comment: pink means that textures are missing. You didn't pack the textures as part of your file. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Comment: Thank you, you've been a big help :)