# Cannot assign material to object, shows up wrong

Tags: materials

So I am trying to make a Roblox GFX, and I made the structure of the person in Roblox Studio, then exported as obj into blender.

I changed to Cycles render before doing anything, then added in my obj. I clicked on the snowball thing (material applier) and clicked material, but it is not right.

It is supposed to look like my character, it is instead neon pink. Here is a picture. I am on Blender 2.79

[image]

Comment: hello, we can't see your picture, pink means it misses the image texture, so either it is not packed into the file, or you need to plug the Image Texture node correctly

Comment: check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Comment: Please vote to close the q so it gets into the review queue @moonboots

Answer (score 0):

Try to UV unwrap it and than appling the texture.
If you just want to add a material go to the material tab and click add material.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this roblox thing before by exporting the characters into blender and the same happened to me. What you used im guessing in roblox is the addon that allows you to search up the username of people on roblox and import their avatar into the roblox scene. You then exported it as obj because that is basically the only export option and put it into blender to maybe reander a roblox front cover or something. As you can see if you click on the character and go to the materials tab that there are textures but they arent showing up. This is propably because the material texture could not be found because it doesnt export textures only the models. so if you go into node editor (shader editor in 2.8) you can find that the nodes are a bit wierd. Just delete them and replace them with an image texture connected to a  diffuse bsdf. Now what I realised is that when I went back into the roblox scene to see if i could export the individual textures from the characters so what you do is you go into your roblox studio and click on the character. There you go through the heirarchy until you find an image or texture and you can click on that an export it. Then you go to the image node in the node editor and browse for the directory of that texture and you have it not lost and pink but the real skin! Hope this helps!