# Rendering my freshly created diamond gives no good result

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

I am a beginner at Blender and very enthusiastic about the enormous possibilities. It is a flood of options.
I started with the creation of a sparkling diamond as a part of a logo for my daughters business. I found a perfect youtube tutorial and succeeded making the diamond. After making the diamond I let turn the animated diamond. It looks very realistic! I am proud at myself! But...
When I start rendering the diamond animation or rendering the image I got a very strange result. See my image from the result. I tried in my opinion everything but no result.
I run Blender on my iMac Pro.

Who can help me?

[image]

The image shows the diamond animation in layout. It was constructed using a youtube video (Making Awesome Diamond Shader in Eevee - Blender Tutorial by VFX Mastro).
It looks for me as a perfect diamond!

Render animation shows on the left the red diamond output using the Evee engine and the output setting on the right side.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we see your world material?

Answer (score 3):

Purple = a linked image is not found.
so as @frederik wrote, it's something related to a material of the world (HDR image) that is not found by blender

Comment: Hi. Thnx. Thats a clear answer. I go directly into it!

Comment: Frequently asked question... no need to repeat that: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink/5372