# All the images are pink

Tags: image, blend-files

When I open an image in the blender, (reference, background, UV-editing, image texture) It always opens as pink colour. I also tried to find missing files option, but it didn't worked. I am desperate and can't do anything related to image in the blender.

Comment: Pink means that blender cannot find the image. Was the image moved to a different folder, or renamed?

Comment: No. The image is also pink even at the first time I opened them.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink