# Midway through rendering my animation, the color management seems to have changed. How did this happen, what should I do?

Tags: color-management

[image: Picture A]
[image: Picture B]

The first image is what I had been rendering (it's frame 36/255) and the second is what it changed to on frame 37/255. I have no idea how this happened and I can't find a way to fix it. (Cycles render btw)

Extra clarification:
The colors aren't the 'texture not found' colors, they are just different, again it changed midway through the rendering process. The textures used are principle BSDF nodes with a change in the base color.

Comment: Did you delete or move any of the images used in the scene? Pink means that blender can no longer access the image file.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink