# Textures are missing, but only when I render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, export

I was trying to make an animation but for some reason when I try to render it or just go into render view the materials are all pink.

I seen other posts about a similar problem of the textures not being linked to the file or whatever but that's not the issue, the textures appear when I'm in material view. I have it set to render using CPU in my user preferences. This is happening for all my projects in Cycles render. The few projects that I made in Blender render when I first began do not have this problem.

[image: this is what it looks like rendered]

Comment: You are missing an image in the file. Go to *file>external data>report missing files* and blender will tell you which files are missing. *file>external data>find missing files* to locate them. Read [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink) for more information.

Comment: @duarte thats not the problem, the files arent missing theyre just not there when i render, i tried doing the file>external data>find missing files thing but it did nothing

Comment: i found out it was cos for some reason in blender 2.78 png images dont render by default. Still havent figured out how to fix that tho so if someone knows just lmk. I seen in an answer to a question that you have to go to the image texture node and click use alpha but that didnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

You might move your textures or renamed it
So u just replace it in same location or use external data/find missing files feature
When u want to  email it just some one just pack all textures by this feature external data/pack all files

Comment: the files arent actually missing I can see them when I am in material mode, theyre only not there when I render or am in render view.