# why my donut's bun color changed?

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders

[image: this is what i get to see in my layout mode in blender]I almost completed my donut guru tutorial but after completing the coffee cup I unhide my donut but I don't know why but it's bun color has changed . I am sharing the link of my file below . kindly check it out and tell me what's wrong with the bun . It will be a great help.
thank you all.
https://pasteall.org/media/b/e/be65a7a41703b31185d925409504c348.blend

Comment: hello, please only share the object(s) you want us to see, plus you didn't pack the image you've used, your bun is pink because there's an image missing, to pack image go into File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/5/b/5bf37101be6e9934e178100875d4b2f1.blend  here is the packed file @moonboots

Comment: Also, please add some screenshots of the problem to the question. If this is a bug in blender related to hardware, sending just the file would leave it hidden.

Comment: your donut is still pink, you haven't packed the image called "donut texture"

Comment: @moonboots that is the only problem i am facing , that is why even packing the bun is still pink in color i have added an image too though

Comment: if the problem is that the color is pink, it's because Blender can't find the image that the bun is supposed to use in its material, it is called "donut texture"  and it was not packed btw, so yes it must be missing, go into File > External Data > Find Missing File

Comment: see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink

Comment: yes @moonboots thankyou for your help