Im trying to help my young son try and save his 3d model with materials intact!
My young son is very much into Roblox and is now trying to learn blender.
He has watched tutorials and has made his object for the game, added the material etc... but when (he saves the file) tries to pack his model, all he gets is this message:
X Unable to pack file, source pathC\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\Desktop\game model saves\ not found
If he imports the model, it is there minus the materials.
So basically a purple model minus the details.
Sorry if this doesn't make sense, Im just trying to help him and dont use blender myself, and he is only very young.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

I assume you're trying to pack your external data via Blender's File > External Data > Pack Resources before saving the Blend file? It sounds as if Blender can't find the file path to the material files. Maybe something to do with having 'Onedrive' in the file path, but without knowing your setup it's difficult to say.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
